# Swift: How can I change the background color randomly every second?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, random, nstimer

My code below gives me a random background color from my array of colors, every time I open the app, but does not change the color every second. What did I do wrong here?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var timer = NSTimer()

func randomColorGenerator() -> Int{
    let randomColor = Int(arc4random_uniform(4))
    return randomColor
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let colors = [
        UIColor(red: 233/255, green: 203/255, blue: 198/255, alpha: 1),
        UIColor(red: 38/255, green: 188/255, blue: 192/255, alpha: 1),
        UIColor(red: 253/255, green: 221/255, blue: 164/255, alpha: 1),
        UIColor(red: 235/255, green: 154/255, blue: 171/255, alpha: 1),
        UIColor(red: 87/255, green: 141/255, blue: 155/255, alpha: 1)
    ]

     timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("randomColorGenerator"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    let randColor = ViewController().randomColorGenerator()
    self.view.backgroundColor = colors[randColor]
}
```

Comment: Does the randomColorGenerator method apply the color to the screen as well?

Comment: The randomColorGenerator returns a random number which is then used to set randColor as the random number, which is then used in "self.view.backgroundColor = colors[randColor]".  Should I include the change background color statement inside the randomColorGenerator method?

Comment: What I can see from your code is, your timer is just calling `randomColorGenerator` which returns an `Int` and then nothing else happens.

Comment: on how you set the code your function can not generate more than a random, in that its scope ends at the close of the viewDidLoad

Comment: @D.Khan That's the problem, you're only generating a random number and not setting the screen using the timer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var timer: NSTimer!

    func setRandomBackgroundColor() {
        let colors = [
            UIColor(red: 233/255, green: 203/255, blue: 198/255, alpha: 1),
            UIColor(red: 38/255, green: 188/255, blue: 192/255, alpha: 1),
            UIColor(red: 253/255, green: 221/255, blue: 164/255, alpha: 1),
            UIColor(red: 235/255, green: 154/255, blue: 171/255, alpha: 1),
            UIColor(red: 87/255, green: 141/255, blue: 155/255, alpha: 1)
        ]
        let randomColor = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32 (colors.count)))
        self.view.backgroundColor = colors[randomColor]
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("setRandomBackgroundColor"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        self.setRandomBackgroundColor()
    }
}
```

What I changed: I've renamed your `randomColorGenerator` function into `setRandomBackgroundColor`. Then I made this function to really change color instead of just calculating and returning some random index.

Some other minor changes: `let randomColor = Int(arc4random_uniform(4))` you can use `UInt32(colors.count)` instead of hardcoded constant `4`.

`var timer = NSTimer()` – you don't need to initialize this timer, you are not using this initial value later. It's enough to just declare variable type: `var time: NSTimer!`

In your initial example, you were calculating random index each second, but you were not using it then to actually set the background color.

Comment: Typo in your answer: `colors[randColor]` should be `colors[randomColor]`.

Comment: Even if I change it to "colors[randomColor]", there is an error on the: "let randomColor = Int(arc4random_uniform(colors.count))" line saying cannot convert value of type "Int" to expected argument type UInt32

Comment: Also, I would add the colors to the array in `viewDidLoad` instead of creating a new one every time the method gets called.

Comment: @Eendje, yes, good point, you can make `let colors = [...]` an instance variable (declare it just below `var timer: NSTimer!` line).

Comment: @D.Khan Sorry, I've written this code in the browser and have not checked it in a playground. Can you try again?

Answer (score 1):

@glyuck answer 2019 update :

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.setRandomBackgroundColor), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    self.setRandomBackgroundColor()
}
```

Comment: and NSTimer is Timer

Comment: You should propose an edit (if you have enough rep) instead of posting a duplicated answer providing no additional info, and just bumping a 3 year old question to the front page.